# Unity: Gameobjects with tag, Reset to start location/position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have about 6 GameObjects with Tag (Model) after Move, Scale, Rotate how can I reset them back to start location when I click a button.

I am using Vuforia and Unity.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but did you even try? Store their position, scale and rotation before moving them and then just reset them to these values on click.

Comment: I am a Unity newbie, tried a few ways but I kept getting errors. I will try what you have suggested now. Thanks.

Comment: **tried a few ways..** can you tell the world about what exactly you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have about 6 GameObjects with Tag (Model)

Find them all and store them into array.

```
GameObject[] models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Model");
```

> Move, Scale, Rotate how can I reset them back to start location when I
>   click a button.

Get the position(`Vector3`), scale(`Vector3`) and rotation(`Quaternion`) in the `Start()` function, with a `for` loop and store their values to temporary variables. When the `Button` is clicked, call a function that sets the models position, scale and rotation to those values.

To call a function on a Button click, you can do that from the Editor or from Script. `ButtonInstance.onClick.AddListener(() => yourFunctionToCall());`

> I am a Unity newbie

Nothing complicated here.

[GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

[C# arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm).

[GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

[Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.html)

[Quaternion](http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)

[Unity Tutorials for beginners](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

```
Vector3[] defaultPos;
Vector3[] defaultScale;
Quaternion[] defaultRot;

Transform[] models;

//Attach Button from the Editor
public Button resetButton;

void Start()
{
    //Call to back up the Transform before moving, scaling or rotating the GameObject
    backUpTransform();
}

void backUpTransform()
{
    //Find GameObjects with Model tag
    GameObject[] tempModels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Model");

    //Create pos, scale and rot, Transform array size based on sixe of Objects found
    defaultPos = new Vector3[tempModels.Length];
    defaultScale = new Vector3[tempModels.Length];
    defaultRot = new Quaternion[tempModels.Length];

    models = new Transform[tempModels.Length];

    //Get original the pos, scale and rot of each Object on the transform
    for (int i = 0; i < tempModels.Length; i++)
    {
        models[i] = tempModels[i].GetComponent<Transform>();

        defaultPos[i] = models[i].position;
        defaultScale[i] = models[i].localScale;
        defaultRot[i] = models[i].rotation;
    }
}

//Called when Button is clicked
void resetTransform()
{
    //Restore the all the original pos, scale and rot  of each GameOBject
    for (int i = 0; i < models.Length; i++)
    {
        models[i].position = defaultPos[i];
        models[i].localScale = defaultScale[i];
        models[i].rotation = defaultRot[i];
    }
}


void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    resetButton.onClick.AddListener(() => resetTransform());

}


void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    resetButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Trying it out now

Comment: Works great, and also thank you for the very useful links and commented code. I will be exploring it further with your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

a very easy way with very little coding is to make a prefab of your gameobject and re instantiate them, in which case prefab has the initial state of the object so every value will be reset.
to make it even easier you can make a parent object and make a prefab of that one.

then simply:

```
Destroy(Parent);
Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Parent"));
```